# Java Intstream get the index of a multidimensional array with null value

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

Java Instream I need the index of the element in a 2D array which has null value. I could use 
for single dimensional array i did below and it worked:

```
  IntStream.range(0, myArr.length)
                .filter(x -> myArr[x] == null)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);
```

I could using Streams over Arrays and flatmap get to the object but my intention here is to get the value of `i` and `j` for which `myArr[i][j]` is null.

Comment: Since there is no native tuple type in java you don't get this done without creating you own intTuple type. But since even then a stream solution has to create many objects I would recomend to just do it with neasted for loops

Comment: As Ackdari has said, you need to create your own `IntTuple` if you want to do this for all kinds of 2D arrays, but if you are just dealing with rectangular 2D arrays, i.e. each sub array has the same length, then you can do some maths to figure the index out.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `long` value to carry two `int` values:

```
long both = LongStream.range(0, array.length)
    .flatMap(i -> LongStream.range(0, array[(int)i].length).map(j -> j << 32 | i))
    .filter(l -> array[(int)l][(int)(l>>32)] == null)
    .findFirst().orElse(-1);

int j = (int) (both >> 32), i = (int)both;

if(j >= 0) {
    System.out.println("found ("+i+", "+j+")  "+array[i][j]);
}
```

but that’s not simpler than, e.g.

```
int i, j;
search: {
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var sub = array[i];
        for(j = 0; j < sub.length; j++)
            if(sub[j] == null) break search;
    }
    j = -1;
}

if(j >= 0) {
    System.out.println("found ("+i+", "+j+")  "+array[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Indeed sometimes simplicity takes the precedence.. :) thanks for adding another perspective..

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Stream.iterate` and `flatMap` to put all the indices for which the value is `null` in a `SimpleEntry` where key is the first index and the value the second index:

```
 Integer[][] integers = {{1, 2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, null, 11}};
 List<SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> collect = 
            Stream.iterate(0, (i) -> i < integers.length, (i) -> ++i)
                .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, integers[i].length)
                      .filter(j -> integers[i][j] == null)
                      .mapToObj(j -> new SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(i, j))) 
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

 System.out.println(collect);
```

Then for all entries in the `collect` list `integers[entry.getKey()][entry.getValue()] == null` is `true`

EDIT:
The problem itself is trivial the only decision to be made is what container should be used for storing the indices. Here a "natural" solution with `Integer`arrays:

```
    List<Integer[]> collect1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < integers[i].length; j++){
            if (integers[i][j] == null){
                collect1.add(new Integer[]{i, j});
            }
        }
    }

    collect1.forEach(arr -> System.out.println("null at " +arr[0] + "," + arr[1]));
```

Comment: yeah i mean its more like a workaround, i was thinking if there was a more natural solution to this problem in java..

Comment: there is a natural solution in java using a double loop, but this is how you could do it with streams in java without using a custom Tuple class.